# Why does not my clang-format support PPDirectiveIndentStyle option?

Tags: c++, homebrew, clang-format

Installed newest version clang-format on OSX:

```
$ brew upgrade clang-format
Error: clang-format 2018-04-24 already installed
$ clang-format -version
clang-format version 7.0.0 (tags/google/stable/2018-04-24)
```

And got one line in _clang-format file to format my C++ code:

```
PPDirectiveIndentStyle: AfterHash
```

which lead to error like this:

```
YAML:17:25: error: unknown key 'PPDirectiveIndentStyle'
PPDirectiveIndentStyle: AfterHash
```

I googled, got that this option is introduced at 2017.8 [[Ref](https://github.com/llvm-mirror/clang/commit/31c7a3b61a7c35ae586c7e36fbff1361e051d5ad)]. So it should be supported. How could I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Finally solved! The key should be `IndentPPDirectives`. Like these:

```
IndentPPDirectives: AfterHash
```

Answer (score 0):

"IndentPPDirectives:BeforeHash" is not working, i use too much preprocessing directive and it literally annoying